# Bind Hostname for Public IP Address of Instance of Oracle Cloud Infrastructure (Free Tier Account)

Tags: dns, hostname, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I brought hostname from "namecheap.com". im tried to bind hostname for Public IP of my OCI instance by creating Zone but they didnt give permission to create Zone file.

Is there any way to do this. is there any free services for bind hostname for public ip without redirect

*"this is my first time of apply dns for hosted ip"*

[image: zone file adding]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have reached your service limits. Please check your service limit by following this document about [service limits](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/General/Concepts/servicelimits.htm#top) and raise a service limit increase request by following this guide [Requesting a Service Limit Increase](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/General/Concepts/servicelimits.htm#Requesti).